# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/libpthread_nonshared.a

Tags: gcc, ld

I have the following problem when I try to compile a C program.

```
gcc -I /tmp/test/usr/include -pthread test.c -o test
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/libpthread_nonshared.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable is right (it already contains all my custom paths with my custom libraries in /tmp/test/usr/lib64, /tmp/test/lib64, ...), and I have a copy of the "libpthread_nonshared.a" file in "/tmp/test/usr/lib64/libpthread_nonshared.a".

GCC seems to ignore my custom paths and keeps searching for that file in "/usr/lib64".
I can not make a symlink or stuff like that because I'm not root on the machine.

Any hint?

Thank you! :-D